# How Can Play EasyMovieTexture for ios in Unity?

Tags: ios, file, video, path, local

my questions is simple.

I have Asset EasyMovieTexture in Unity. So, i want play video file to use this Asset. but can't get local video file path. how can get local video file?

and is this used for any form address?

```
ex1 : /var/mobile/media/.../movie.MOV
ex2 : assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=123123 ...
ex3 : others..?
```

need help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are making this for the standalone player (PC, Mac and Linux) you need to place the MovieTexture onto an object in the scene. Then, in a script, declare a public MovieTexture and whenever you want it to play you can simply call MovieTexture.Play().

If, however, you are making this for mobile iOS and Android devices, you cannot use MovieTextures in the way you describe. In order to play video files on mobile, you will need to create a new folder in the Assets folder called *StreamingAssets*, and place your video file in the new *StreamingAssets* folder. In a script, you can then call:

Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie("filepath");

And that will play your video in a full screen player. Note that you do not require a full filepath, only the path within your *StreamingAssets* folder. So if your movie was called "Movie.mp4" and it was in your *StreamingAssets* folder, you would call:

Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie("Movie.mp4");

If it was within a folder called *Videos* within *StreamingAssets*, you would need to specify:

Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie("Videos/Movie.mp4");

There are also available a few plugins on the Asset Store that allow you to use MovieTextures on mobile devices, but none of them are free and some of them don't work in Unity 5.

Comment: Thank you. :)

But, in android i was used local file path '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/movie.mp4'. It's my device's video realpath. if you want to load local file, just add 'file://'. (file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/movie.mp4).

i know, need using streaming asset folder. but My question is another problem.

what Is assets path format? (used here)
/var/mobile...?
assets-library://asset...?

i want know to this answer. And how can convert path.

Comment: If you want to get the data path for the Unity project on your device, you can use Application.persistentDataPath.
So making a string filePath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/files/" should result in your app looking in a folder called _files_ within your project.

Comment: But there is no my video within the path. i don't know to my gallery movie file's path in iphone.